# Little Snitch Global rule not working

Tags: macos, firewall

I have a little snitch rule effective in all profiles to allow any process to connect to *.apple.com
[image]
Why do I keep getting request for applications to connect to apple.com? Here are 4 different processes requiring permission. I thought that the rule above should cover these...??
[image]

Comment: Try Domain apple.com - don't use the wildcard (on phone so pics are too small to read)

Comment: @Tetsujin It actually removes the wildcard automatically so you're left with just apple.com

Comment: Hmmm... Ok. I'll have a look later when I'm back at my puter. I've never had the issue so there has to be a setting somewhere...

Comment: @Tetsujin Me neither, it's been working for a long time for me and I've only noticed it recently. I think there was an update to LS recently too so this may have only become an issue since that update...

Comment: Check who the process owner needs to be in the main rule & who 'asked' in the on-demand rules

Comment: @Tetsujin Just checked and both are 'me'

Comment: try setting a dupe for System too - *also*… i just noticed that rule doesn't actually say 'to domain apple.com' it just says 'to apple.com' - that would imply the rule is set to 'hostnames' not 'domains'

Comment: @Tetsujin Doh! Well spotted, changing it to domain has made the other rules redundant. Can you post that so I can mark the question answered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On closer examination of the rule in the picture, it looks like it is set to **Hostnames** apple.com, not **Domains** apple.com, which may make all the difference.

If not, try adding a duplicate Domains rule also for System processes, as well as 'My' processes.

If that spits out any duplicates, you can then clear the others.
You may find some are locked - so disable or just leave as a dupe, it won't actually hurt anything.